# How to make SocketIO/aiohttp print to screen every X seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket.io, aiohttp, python-socketio

A SocketIO server created using aiohttp appends a new string to a global dict `zoo` on receiving a `addAnimal` message from its socketio clients.

Is it possible to also print out the dict `zoo` every 5 seconds? My current code below does not seem to print `zoo` every 5 seconds.

```
import time
from aiohttp import web
import socketio

zoo = []

sio = socketio.AsyncServer()
app = web.Application()
sio.attach(app)

@sio.on('addAnimal')
async def onAddAnimal(sid, animal):
    zoo.append(animal)
    print('Zoo: ', zoo)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app)

    while True:
        print('Zoo:', zoo)
        time.delay(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
from aiohttp import web
import socketio

zoo = []

sio = socketio.AsyncServer()
app = web.Application()
sio.attach(app)


async def print_zoo(interval: int):
    while True:
        print(zoo)
        await asyncio.sleep(interval)


@sio.on('addAnimal')
async def onAddAnimal(sid, animal):
    zoo.append(animal)
    print('Zoo: ', zoo)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.ensure_future(print_zoo(5))
    web.run_app(app)
```